# Running falcon ai model on mojo lang

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, huggingface-transformers, huggingface, mojolang

How can we run https://huggingface.co/tiiuae/falcon-180B the one of the current best models on mojo lang which is faster than python 35k? When we just copy this:

```
`from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
import transformers
import torch

model = "tiiuae/falcon-180b"

tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)
pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
    "text-generation",
    model=model,
    tokenizer=tokenizer,
    torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
    trust_remote_code=True,
    device_map="auto",
)
sequences = pipeline(
   "Girafatron is obsessed with giraffes, the most glorious animal on the face of this Earth. Giraftron believes all other animals are irrelevant when compared to the glorious majesty of the giraffe.\nDaniel: Hello, Girafatron!\nGirafatron:",
    max_length=200,
    do_sample=True,
    top_k=10,
    num_return_sequences=1,
    eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
)
for seq in sequences:
    print(f"Result: {seq['generated_text']}")
```

`

we got error as below:

`

```
error: TODO: expressions are not yet supported at the file scope level
model = "tiiuae/falcon-180b"
^
hello.mojo:7:1: error: use of unknown declaration 'model'
model = "tiiuae/falcon-180b"
^~~~~
hello.mojo:9:1: error: TODO: expressions are not yet supported at the file scope level
tokenizer = AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)
^
hello.mojo:3:6: error: unable to locate module 'transformers'
from transformers import AutoTokenizer, AutoModelForCausalLM
     ^
hello.mojo:10:1: error: TODO: expressions are not yet supported at the file scope level
pipeline = transformers.pipeline(
^
hello.mojo:18:1: error: TODO: expressions are not yet supported at the file scope level
sequences = pipeline(
^
hello.mojo:18:13: error: use of unknown declaration 'pipeline'
sequences = pipeline(
            ^~~~~~~~
hello.mojo:26:12: error: use of unknown declaration 'sequences'
for seq in sequences:
           ^~~~~~~~~
hello.mojo:27:5: error: TODO: expressions are not yet supported at the file scope level
    print(f"Result: {seq['generated_text']}")
    ^
hello.mojo:27:12: error: expected ')' in call argument list
    print(f"Result: {seq['generated_text']}")
           ^
hello.mojo:27:12: error: statements must start at the beginning of a line
    print(f"Result: {seq['generated_text']}")
           ^
mojo: error: failed to parse the provided Mojo
```

`

When the code from hugging face is copied and pasted in mojo environment, model should be running.

Comment: Mojo Lang does not currently support running plain python code, simple as that.

Answer (score 2):

i'm having the same issue, i think they haven't rolled out many of the feature

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

first you need to install all the dependencies in your base enviroment if you are using conda because that's from where mojo reads python packages then try this piece of code :

```
from python import Python
def main():
    let t = Python.import_module("transformers")
    let torch = Python.import_module("torch")
    let model = "tiiuae/falcon-180b"
    
    let tokenizer = t.AutoTokenizer.from_pretrained(model)
    let pipeline = t.pipeline(
        "text-generation",
        model=model,
        tokenizer=tokenizer,
        torch_dtype=torch.bfloat16,
        trust_remote_code=True,
        device_map="auto",
    )
    let sequences = pipeline(
        "Girafatron is obsessed with giraffes, the most glorious animal on the face of this Earth. Giraftron believes all other animals are irrelevant when compared to the glorious majesty of the giraffe.\nDaniel: Hello, Girafatron!\nGirafatron:",
        max_length=200,
        do_sample=True,
        top_k=10,
        num_return_sequences=1,
        eos_token_id=tokenizer.eos_token_id,
    )
    for seq in sequences:
        let seq_printed=seq['generated_text']
        print("Result: ", seq_printed)
```

Comment: Thanks. Tried to install via here https://medium.com/@parham.motameni/install-conda-on-wsl2-2e76d1e03229, seems that didn't work `Unhandled exception caught during execution: An error occurred in Python.
mojo: error: execution exited with a non-zero result: 1`

Comment: you should login in  with your hugging face  account in conda first because  it's a gated repo  ,I got this error as I don't have access to it  :                               'HTTPError: 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://huggingface.co/tiiuae/falcon-180b/resolve/main/tokenizer_config.json
'

Comment: Also you should run **pip install  einops accelerate** , if it respond with the same error just restart the kernel